# How to install matlab if I already have a Windows version?

Tags: wine, matlab

I am new to Ubuntu and confused about whether to use Matlab windows version (which I had a copy) using WINE or to install the Linux version.

If it is good to install Linux version of Matlab I would like a detailed set of instructions to install it.

Comment: do you have installation DVD or you have downloaded the .iso ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have already a copy of MATLAB, then you could follow these steps to install on your Ubuntu machine (assuming you have a downloaded copy).

1. First make a mount point, which is just a folder. For example:

   ```
   mkdir /media/mathworks
   ```
2. Then mount the downloaded ISO to that directory. For this example,
   the ISO is in the home folder under the downloads folder and the ISO
   is called `matlab.iso`(if you have downloaded on to the same system):

   ```
   mount -t iso9660 -o loop ~/downloads/matlab.iso /media/mathworks
   ```
3. Now you can navigate there and run the installer as if it were a
   copy of the DVD, for example:

   ```
   cd /media/mathworks
   ./install
   ```